# Returna list of selected points from selectpoints3d in R

Tags: r

I have created a 3d plot using rgl package, which consist of 2000 data and I would like to select points in the plot for further analysis. I've managed to do that using selectpoints3d. But, how do I return the list of the points selected?

```
    fit3x <- fit3[,1]
    fit3y <- fit3[,2]
    fit3z <- fit3[,3]
    ids <- plot3d(fit3x, fit3y, fit3z, col=rep(c("blue","green","yellow"),c(776,774,701)),pch=19)
    test1 <- selectpoints3d(ids, multiple = function(x) {spheres3d(x, color = "red", alpha = 0.3, radius = 0.2)},TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `ESC` to stop selecting points, then identify the indices e.g. like this:

```
mat <- matrix(c(fit3x, fit3y, fit3z), ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y", "z")))
mat <- round(mat, 2); test1 <- round(test1, 2)
which(apply(mat, 1, function(x) any(apply(test1, 1, function(y) all(x == y)))))
```